# TypeScript fails type resolution on union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

Say that you have something which can either be an array of numbers or strings and you want to map over this array. Using TypeScript the following ways of expressing such a situation are all accepted by the type checker.

```
[1, 2].map(e => console.log(e));
let arr: string[] | number[] = [1, 2];
arr.map(e => console.log(e));
```

But if we add an explicit static type cast, to the same type, to describe arr the compiler will throw an error our way:

```
(arr as string[] | number[]).map(e => console.log(e)); 
// Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
// Type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Do you know why this would happen, or is it possible that this is an issue with the compiler itself?

Comment: To get that to work I believe you'd have to use the intersection type: `(arr as string[] & number[]).map(e => console.log(e)); `. Either that, or use a type guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually seeing flow control analysis in action in the first case. Since you only assign a number array to your variable the compiler will decide that the actual type for `arr` is `number[]` and it will run with that, making the `map` call valid. If you actually assign a `string[]` to the variable, with the compiler not being able to statically decide which code path will actually be taken you will receive the same error as you do with an explicit cast:

```
declare var decider : boolean
let arr: string[] | number[] = decider ? [1, 2] : ['a', 'b'];
arr.map(e => console.log(e)); // Will be an error
```

As to why `map` is not callable on the union of `string[] | number[]` the reason is that the type of `map` will be a union type of the two available signatures from `string[]` and `number[]` the signatures are not identical and no merging will occur between them. Since a union of two signatures is not callable, you will get the error.